# jQuery Datatables.net Collapsible expandible rows - Passing parameters

Tags: jquery, datatables-1.10

I am trying to implement a datatable with expandible and collapsible rows similar to the code here :

https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

I have gotten the code to expand and collapse the rows working but I'm experiencing difficulty in passing the values of the expanded row to my function when the details.control icon is clicked. eg. Upon clicking the expand icon(details-control) I'm trying to expand the row and populate it with data obtained via an ajax request dependent on some of the parent rows data. So some of the parent rows data needs to be passed to my ajax call. How do I obtain said rows data. My code is as follows below :

```
$('#myTable').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
   var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
   var row = oTable.row(tr);
// need to get row data here somehow
   var rowId = ?????

   if (row.child.isShown()) {
       // This row is already open - close it
       row.child.hide();
       tr.removeClass('shown');
   } else {
       // Open this row
       format(row.child,rowid);
       tr.addClass('shown');
   }
 });


  function format(callback, id) {
   $.ajax({
       url: "@Url.Action("foo", "bar")/"+ id,
       dataType: "json",
       complete: function (response) {
           var data = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
           var thead = '', tbody = '';
           for (var key in data[0]) {
               //thead += '<th>' + key + '</th>';
           }

           $.each(data, function (i, d) {
               for (var x = 0; x < d.length ; x++)
               {
                   tbody += '<tr><td style="width:290px">' + d[x].Description + '</td><td style="width:210px">' + d[x].BalanceBroughtForward + '</td><td style="width:100px">' + d[x].Payments + '</td><td style="width:100px">' +
                 '</td></tr>';

               }
           });
           callback($('<table>' + thead + tbody + '</table>')).show();
       },
       error: function () {
           $('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
       }
   });
```

Comment: First Put a breakpoint near row Id and check what u r getting to row in console....

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the datatables api documentation and by trial and error I managed to get this working by using the following :

```
  $('#myTable').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = oTable.row(tr);
        var rowdata = (oTable.row(tr).data());
        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        } else {
            console.log( oTable.row(tr).data());
            // Open this row
            format(row.child, oTable.row(tr).data());
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });
```

Any better, more elegant solutions are welcome.
Cheers.